# Dictionary using a class as Parameter and Key, CRUD C#

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, data-structures, contains

So i need to create a **data-structure** with **one Key**, **sub Key** and **Value**. And a method to Add Key, sub Key and Value.

The **Key** are **unique** and can have **multiple** **Sub Keys**.

The **Sub Key** are **uniques** in the context inside **Key** and can have multiple **Values**.

The **Values** are **unique** inside the context of the **Sub Key**.

The first data-structure that comes to my mind was **Dictionary** (perform time is important for the task).
Then i created the following dictionary.

```
    public class NewCollection : IHoplonCollection
{
    class SubIndexAndValue
    {
        public int subIndex;
        public List<string> Value = new List<string>();
    }

    class DataStructure : IComparable<DataStructure>
    {
        public string Key;
        public List<SubIndexAndValue> subIndexValue = new List<SubIndexAndValue>();

        public int CompareTo(DataStructure other)
        {
            if (Key.CompareTo(other.Key) > 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }else if (Key.CompareTo(other.Key) < 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    SortedDictionary<DataStructure, SubIndexAndValue> colList = new SortedDictionary<DataStructure, SubIndexAndValue>();

    public bool Add(string Key, int subIndex, string Value)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

So as you can see the **Add** method will receive the **Key**, **Sub Key** and **Value**.

In the future i will need to do a CRUD and sort data.

My question is, how do i handle this? How can i use method like Contains() to check if one **Value** (string) was already inserted in the dictionary using this data-structure? Or maybe there is an easyer way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Another way potential way `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<int,string>>`

Comment: Override Equals and GetHashCode methods in the Class that you want to make Key of the Dictionary. Also, food for thought - Why cant you have Key_SubKey string as Key and List<T> as the value.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava yeah Key_SubKey is probably less fuss in some ways

Comment: @MichaelRandall - :) Glad to hear from you One 2 One. Hope you are keeping well and stocked in these crazy times.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava stocked up on coffee and resharper subscriptions, ill survive the Apocalypse yet

Comment: I think you meant `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<int,HashSet<string>>>`

Answer (score 0):

I think that a combination of built-in structures can solve your proposed datastructure:

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<int,HashSet<string>>>
```

The first dictionary holds list of key-value pairs of `string` (**Key**), and for every one of them, the value it's another Dictionary whose key is a unique `string` (**SubKey**) and the value is a `HashSet<string>`, a list of unique strings.